# What does ''developing the intel'' mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

While watching the first episode of season 6 of the UK series "Line of duty", one of the character who is a leading detective in a case told another detective to "continue developing the intel". My question is what does "develop" here mean? Is it to keep searching/collecting the intel?
To put the sentence into a context I'll provide their dialogue which as as follows:

**Character A:** We just had a call from a CHIS Handler submitting information relevant to Vella.

**Character B:** What did they say?

**Character A:** Possible suspect. A person so far unknown to the inquiry, alleged to have made a confession.

**Character B:** Okay. Continue developing the intel.

Comment: I wonder why you haven't asked what 'intel' means.

Answer (score 1):

OED

**develop** (v.)

> **5. a. (a)** *transitive.* **To bring (something) to a fuller or more advanced state; to improve, extend.**
>
> 1741   tr. L. Racine in tr. Select Disc. Acad. Belles Lettres 36   *Men recovered the Habitude of Thinking, which they had lost; and at the same time learned to develop and express their Thoughts.*
>
> 1971   R. Brewer Approach to Print xiii. 151   *The printing plant itself can be centrally developed to an advanced stage of efficiency.*
>
> 2004   Time Out N.Y. 4 Nov. 161/2   *We have so much more time to develop the character and get hyperdetailed about the various sides of this guy's life.*